# Compare two XML attributes with same name in two different XML files

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I need to compare a set of large data of about 600 android attributes with another XML file which may contain some of these above 600 attributes.If any of them are present I had to output 1 or else 0.So the output must be of the form of a string of 600 1's and zeroes.Please help me to get this code compatible with Android Studio.
Example xml file which I had to compare

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<manifest package="eu.enisa.se_cure"xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>


-<application android:name="eu.enisa.se_cure.Core" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:allowBackup="true">


-<activity android:name="eu.enisa.se_cure.MainScreen" android:label="@string/app_name">


 -<intent-filter>

 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name="eu.enisa.se_cure.Scanning" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

<receiver android:name="eu.enisa.se_cure.SecureAlarm"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The source file contains as many as 600 attributes which may contain in this file.For the attributes that are present the output must be 1 or else 0

Comment: please post the xml sample and what you have tried

Comment: @vtd-xml-author I had edited as per ur request.Plz do check